# Importing large Outlook Express mail to Outlook

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-outlook, import, microsoft-outlook-2003

I am in the process of moving all my Outlook Express email (over 5GB) to Outlook 2003.  I will then move that .pst file to Outlok on a new Win 8 computer.

My problem is my OE files are so large they won't fit in a .pst file that is in 97-2002 format and I can't seem to find a way to import them to a .pst file I created that is in 2003 format.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include the answer. Instead answer your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Edit from @PeteC relocated here pending OP creating answer: I solved this problem. It is very subtle. It is not apparent that changing the "Deliver new e-mail to the following location" can change the format for all the email accounts. Also, I couldn't tell that clicking "New Outlook Data File" and selecting the new 2003 format will automatically import everything to the new format Personal Folders.

Comment: I forget what the official size limit was for pst files in Outlook 2003, but even in 2007, Outlook was unreliable when the pst file exceeded about 1 GB.  You can have many pst files open at once, though.  The prudent thing to do with 5 GB of OE files is to divide them into multiple pst files (based on subject, age, or whatever), and open as many of them as you need.  Once everything is in pst files, you can also easily reorganize the messages to create an active file and archive the rest.